# SVG stroke and fill animation

Tags: css, animation, svg, inkscape

I am in a deep learning about SVG and how they work ([following this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)). I want to make a simple animation with SVG which animate the stroke and then fill it with some color. For the moment, what I've achieved is to animate the stroke, but I can't fill it.

I want also to remove the "unnecesary `metatags` or elements" which not define the geometry without change it's behaviour, but I don't know which elements may be removed.

```css
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 15s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg6"
   version="1.1"
   xml:space="preserve"
   viewBox="0 0 40 25"
   height="25"
   width="40"><metadata
     id="metadata41"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
         rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /><dc:title></dc:title></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
     id="defs39" /><path
     id="path2" class="path"
     d="m 20,-0.0390625 c -8.738524,0 -16.3133051,5.0886654 -20.03515625,12.5214845 l -0.0078125,0.01758 0.0078125,0.01758 C 3.6866949,19.950397 11.261476,25.039062 20,25.039062 c 8.73829,0 16.313149,-5.088665 20.035156,-12.521484 l 0.0078,-0.01758 -0.0078,-0.01758 C 36.313305,5.0496023 28.73829,-0.0390625 20,-0.0390625 Z m 0,0.078125 c 8.700471,0 16.240477,5.0636856 19.953125,12.4609375 C 36.240322,19.897253 28.700471,24.960938 20,24.960938 11.299295,24.960938 3.7595231,19.897252 0.046875,12.5 3.7595231,5.1027475 11.299295,0.0390625 20,0.0390625 Z m -3.75,4.6875 c -2.092204,0 -3.789062,1.6968522 -3.789062,3.7890625 0,2.0922 1.696858,3.789063 3.789062,3.789063 2.092204,0 3.789062,-1.696863 3.789062,-3.789063 0,-2.0922103 -1.696858,-3.7890625 -3.789062,-3.7890625 z m 0,0.078125 c 2.049984,0 3.710938,1.6609478 3.710938,3.7109375 0,2.04998 -1.660954,3.710937 -3.710938,3.710937 -2.049984,0 -3.710938,-1.660957 -3.710938,-3.710937 0,-2.0499897 1.660954,-3.7109375 3.710938,-3.7109375 z m -5.574219,1.4492187 -0.09375,0.056641 C 10.426237,6.4035843 10.270636,6.4978471 10.117188,6.5957031 7.7622896,8.0977374 5.7663923,10.109501 4.2675781,12.478516 L 4.2558594,12.5 l 0.011719,0.02148 c 1.4988914,2.368853 3.4947124,4.380629 5.8496099,5.882813 2.959123,1.887486 6.376963,2.884765 9.882812,2.884765 3.50577,0 6.923687,-0.997279 9.882812,-2.884765 2.354897,-1.502114 4.350794,-3.513878 5.84961,-5.882813 L 35.744141,12.5 35.732422,12.478516 C 34.233529,10.109583 32.237867,8.0978175 29.882812,6.5957031 29.729351,6.4977886 29.573504,6.4035804 29.417969,6.3105469 l -0.09375,-0.056641 0.03711,0.1035157 c 0.387382,1.0633953 0.59961,2.210705 0.59961,3.4082031 0,5.501618 -4.459316,9.960937 -9.960938,9.960937 -5.501701,0 -9.960938,-4.459319 -9.960938,-9.960937 0,-1.1974981 0.212152,-2.34489 0.59961,-3.4082031 z M 10.548828,6.421875 c -0.370873,1.047471 -0.5878905,2.1692414 -0.5878905,3.34375 0,5.543842 4.4951375,10.039062 10.0390625,10.039063 5.543846,0 10.039062,-4.495221 10.039062,-10.039063 0,-1.1745086 -0.21709,-2.2962074 -0.58789,-3.34375 0.130547,0.078683 0.260001,0.1581373 0.388672,0.2402344 C 32.177279,8.152986 34.157303,10.150888 35.648438,12.5 34.15738,14.84911 32.177125,16.847013 29.839844,18.337891 26.893187,20.217424 23.490948,21.210937 20,21.210938 c -3.491027,0 -6.893188,-0.993514 -9.839844,-2.873047 C 7.8228755,16.846944 5.8426963,14.849033 4.3515625,12.5 5.8426188,10.15081 7.8228763,8.1529063 10.160156,6.6621094 10.288838,6.5800473 10.418191,6.5005372 10.548828,6.421875 Z"
     style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1;" /></svg>
```

P.S: I've created the SVG with Inkscape, grouping all in one group and using the option "Stroke to path" to make only 1 stroke and animate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "fill".  Your icon has been designed with a fill that is very thin, and looks like a stroke.

If we turn off the stroke and give it a red fill, it looks like this:

```css
.path {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg6"
   version="1.1"
   xml:space="preserve"
   viewBox="0 0 40 25"
   height="250"
   width="400"><metadata
     id="metadata41"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
         rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /><dc:title></dc:title></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
     id="defs39" /><path
     id="path2" class="path"
     d="m 20,-0.0390625 c -8.738524,0 -16.3133051,5.0886654 -20.03515625,12.5214845 l -0.0078125,0.01758 0.0078125,0.01758 C 3.6866949,19.950397 11.261476,25.039062 20,25.039062 c 8.73829,0 16.313149,-5.088665 20.035156,-12.521484 l 0.0078,-0.01758 -0.0078,-0.01758 C 36.313305,5.0496023 28.73829,-0.0390625 20,-0.0390625 Z m 0,0.078125 c 8.700471,0 16.240477,5.0636856 19.953125,12.4609375 C 36.240322,19.897253 28.700471,24.960938 20,24.960938 11.299295,24.960938 3.7595231,19.897252 0.046875,12.5 3.7595231,5.1027475 11.299295,0.0390625 20,0.0390625 Z m -3.75,4.6875 c -2.092204,0 -3.789062,1.6968522 -3.789062,3.7890625 0,2.0922 1.696858,3.789063 3.789062,3.789063 2.092204,0 3.789062,-1.696863 3.789062,-3.789063 0,-2.0922103 -1.696858,-3.7890625 -3.789062,-3.7890625 z m 0,0.078125 c 2.049984,0 3.710938,1.6609478 3.710938,3.7109375 0,2.04998 -1.660954,3.710937 -3.710938,3.710937 -2.049984,0 -3.710938,-1.660957 -3.710938,-3.710937 0,-2.0499897 1.660954,-3.7109375 3.710938,-3.7109375 z m -5.574219,1.4492187 -0.09375,0.056641 C 10.426237,6.4035843 10.270636,6.4978471 10.117188,6.5957031 7.7622896,8.0977374 5.7663923,10.109501 4.2675781,12.478516 L 4.2558594,12.5 l 0.011719,0.02148 c 1.4988914,2.368853 3.4947124,4.380629 5.8496099,5.882813 2.959123,1.887486 6.376963,2.884765 9.882812,2.884765 3.50577,0 6.923687,-0.997279 9.882812,-2.884765 2.354897,-1.502114 4.350794,-3.513878 5.84961,-5.882813 L 35.744141,12.5 35.732422,12.478516 C 34.233529,10.109583 32.237867,8.0978175 29.882812,6.5957031 29.729351,6.4977886 29.573504,6.4035804 29.417969,6.3105469 l -0.09375,-0.056641 0.03711,0.1035157 c 0.387382,1.0633953 0.59961,2.210705 0.59961,3.4082031 0,5.501618 -4.459316,9.960937 -9.960938,9.960937 -5.501701,0 -9.960938,-4.459319 -9.960938,-9.960937 0,-1.1974981 0.212152,-2.34489 0.59961,-3.4082031 z M 10.548828,6.421875 c -0.370873,1.047471 -0.5878905,2.1692414 -0.5878905,3.34375 0,5.543842 4.4951375,10.039062 10.0390625,10.039063 5.543846,0 10.039062,-4.495221 10.039062,-10.039063 0,-1.1745086 -0.21709,-2.2962074 -0.58789,-3.34375 0.130547,0.078683 0.260001,0.1581373 0.388672,0.2402344 C 32.177279,8.152986 34.157303,10.150888 35.648438,12.5 34.15738,14.84911 32.177125,16.847013 29.839844,18.337891 26.893187,20.217424 23.490948,21.210937 20,21.210938 c -3.491027,0 -6.893188,-0.993514 -9.839844,-2.873047 C 7.8228755,16.846944 5.8426963,14.849033 4.3515625,12.5 5.8426188,10.15081 7.8228763,8.1529063 10.160156,6.6621094 10.288838,6.5800473 10.418191,6.5005372 10.548828,6.421875 Z"
     style="stroke:black;stroke-width:0;" /></svg>
```

If you want the area between the lines to be filled, so that it looks more like an eye, then first you are going to need to alter the path.

You'll also need to explain what you mean by "fill it with some colour". Do you mean the fill appears? The fill fades in from white? The fill rises like water in a glass?

Perhaps you are after something like this? [SVG animate. Fill path after drawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674681/svg-animate-fill-path-after-drawn)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was looking for. As I said, maybe the "stroke to path" option makes the fill thin. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Redo your SVG, but this time don't use "stroke to path". That is not what you want.  Remove the stroke colour and give it a fill instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds like you're looking for [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo)

> SVG files, especially exported from various editors, usually contain a lot of redundant and useless information such as editor metadata, comments, hidden elements, default or non-optimal values and other stuff that can be safely removed or converted without affecting SVG rendering result.

According to my experience using `svgo test.svg` which optimise everything may result in strange image bugs. 
Therefore, use the different plugins to optimise your svg step by step.

1. overwrite `--config` attribute full with true to disable all plugins (quite strange yes)
2. enable plugins you want with `--enable`

`svgo --config='{"full":true}' --enable=removeMetadata test.svg`

btw, that animation is quite cool - may need some antialiasing.

Comment: There's a bug on my `path`, it doesn't fill anything because as I said, it is all border. However, I found very interesting your solution to clean and optimize SVG